# How to use local version of a package?

Tags: asp.net-core

In ASP.NET 5 on the `project.json` file we can list dependencies of the project on some nuget packages. If we don't have the package locally then the package is downloaded from the remote source upon the use of `kpm restore` and then we use that package from an external source.

Now, suppose I target one package that's from some open source project and suppose I needed to modify something for my current needs. Since the project is open source I can clone the repository locally and change whatever I need and then make my local version of the nuget package for that project.

My doubt is, how can I refer this local package? I've generated the `.nupkg` then how I reference it on my `project.json` so that in the future if the feature I needed is implemented on the external one I can easily switch to use the one received from the external source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the package (modified) source code instead of the actual package you can do something similar to what is shown [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/02/06/debugging-asp-net-5-framework-code-using-visual-studio-2015.aspx). The article demonstrates how to use the MVC source code instead of packages but it works for any other nupkg.

If you already compiled the package then you can upload the nupkg on myget or a network share and modify the NuGet sources to include the new location.